# The motherboard "GA-945GM-S2" is compatible with processor "Dual Core E2200"?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, compatibility

I have a [Intel® Pentium® Processor E2200](http://ark.intel.com/products/33925/intel-pentium-processor-e2200-1m-cache-2_20-ghz-800-mhz-fsb) processor. I have discovered that my motherboard is faulty. I found the [GA-945GM-S2](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2331#ov), but I do not know if it supports my processor. I need to know if it is compatible before I buy the motherboard.

Comment: The motherboard is a 1.LGA775 motherboard the CPU is a 1.LGA775 
CPU thus the motherboard provided the BIOS firmware that supports the CPU is used will have no problem with the CPU being installed.  **You normally have to have a supported CPU with the current revision of the firmware to update the firmware.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Supported CPU list](http://www.gigabyte.com/support-downloads/cpu-support-popup.aspx?pid=2331) on Gigabyte's website for that motherboard, yes it will support it, as long as BIOS version F6 or newer is loaded onto the motherboard before trying to use it.